# Parse.com linq relational query

Tags: linq, parse-platform, relational

Im using Xamarin.IOS and i want to run simple relations query using LINQ. I have to table. One table is NewSource other one is NewCategory. Two table relational with Name. For example :

NewSource table row:

```
Name: Radikal
Active: true
```

NewCategory table row:

```
NewSourceName: Radikal
Active:true
SportUrl: http://www.something.com
EconomyUrl= http://www.something.com
..
..
```

I wrote this query take from Parse document:

```
var query= from post in ParseObject.GetQuery("NewSource")
                 where (bool)post["Active"]==true //which mean i want to take only active New Source
             select post;

var query2 = from comment in ParseObject.GetQuery("NewCategory")
            join post in query on comment["NewSourcename"] equals post
            select comment;

var comments = await query.FindAsync();
```

The code is not working. it returns always null. Where can i do wrong? I want to relational two table which connect is NewSource.Name and NewCategory.NewSourceName

How can i do this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `NewSource` table's `Name` column linked to `NewSourceName` column in `NewCategory` table, you can try to join them this way :

```
var query2 = from comment in ParseObject.GetQuery("NewCategory")
             join post in query on (string)comment["NewSourcename"] equals (string)post["Name"]
             select comment;
```

Comment: Thank you for answer. I tried but didnt work. Why dont work i dont understand:( I think, problem source Parse. Is possible?

Comment: updated my answer. Maybe it failed because they were read as object and compared by reference instead of value. I assumed that both column are of type string, and expect they will be compared as string value after casting like shown in updated answer.